# how to fix parts of model not being rendered in texture mode

Tags: texturing

can someone tell me how to fix the hands and the back of the neck to be rendered like everything else?

[image]

Comment: Looks like UV issue mate, send please the .blend file.

Comment: I actually somehow fixed it. idk what the hell i did though. but here is the blend file of the working one. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dICnhzT3DlVPhWbXxHEduhawurs8eZCO

Comment: So good U make it working. Btw U upload the scene without textures so I could see NOTHING ;)

Comment: glad everything's working out.

Comment: oh sorry jan :P ya i am still learning